# How to get xml representation of css locator in chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

Expected xml representation here,

[image]

instead it display the below,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've broken it last year under the pretext of unifying array appearance, see [crbug.com/607682](https://crbug.com/607682).

For the time being you can display a single element of jQuery $ by appending `[0]`:

```
$('.some.selector')[0]
```

unroll the arrays with multiple elements via .apply:

```
console.log.apply(console, $('.some.selector'))
```

or define a jQuery wrapper:

```
function $log(selector) { console.log.apply(console, jQuery(selector)) }
```

and use it:

```
$log('.some.selector')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
console.dirxml($("css selector")[0]);
```

When you pass whole resultset from function $("css selector") to `console.dirxml` function, you pass not HTML node, but array (wrapped by jquery) of nodes from your css selector.

Comment: Actually it works even without console.dirxml; but you have to apply [0] as suffix to locator